# useState not working on next js while fetching data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to access data from the API and the response is comming but while I try to set the data to useState that is setAccessData the data is not getting to access Data I have tried many methods its only showing undefined

```
interface Pokedex {
  username: string
}

const [accessData, setAccessData] = useState<Pokedex>({
  username: '',
})

useEffect(() => {
  bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        
  if (bearerToken) {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8004/accesschat`,{userId}, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
          },
        });
        const userData = response.data;
        console.log(userData);
        setAccessData({
          username: userData.users[0].username
        });
        console.log(accessData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }
},[]);
```

I have tried changing the types of typescript

Comment: Why do you say that it's not working? If it's because of the log, that last `console.log(accessData);` won't show the updated data, it's only on the next rerender where the `accessData` state will have the new value.

Comment: What exactly is showing undefined? `console.log(userData)`, `console.log(accessData)` or `console.error(error)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `await` keyword before `response.data`:

```
const userData = **await** response.data;
```